# Issues with I219 Network Adapter and em 7.6.2

Tags: drivers, freebsd, network-interface

I have just installed FreeBSD (11.0-RELEASE-p1) on a system with the Intel I219-V network adapter. This version of FreeBSD has em v7.6.1, which (I believe...maybe it's just the EEPROM checksum error? Read on...) doesn't support this network chipset, so I sought out the updated version, v7.6.2, [from Intel's website](https://downloadcenter.intel.com/download/17509/Intel-Network-Adapter-Gigabit-Base-Driver-for-FreeBSD-?product=82186).

Following the readme, I installed like so:

1. Untar/unzip
2. `make`
3. `make install`
4. Add `if_em_load="YES"` to /boot/loader.conf
5. Add `ifconfig_em0="DHCP"` to /etc/rc.conf

After rebooting, I still receive the following messages in `dmesg.boot`:

```
module_register: cannot register pci/em from kernel; already loaded from if_em.ko
Module pci/em failed to register: 17
...
em0: <Intel (R) PRO/1000 Network Connection 7.6.1-k> mem 0xdf300000-0xdf31ffff irq 16 at device 31.6 on pci0
em0: Using an MSI interrupt
em0: The EEPROM Checksum Is Not Valid
device_attach: em0 attach returned 5
```

And the adapter is not recognized by the system.

There are two things to notice here--the bad checksum, which I will return to later, and the fact that v.7.6.1 is loading, even though I've just installed v7.6.2!

I tried to find out where each version is living:

```
$ strings /boot/kernel/if_em.ko
...
7.6.1-k
...
$ strings /boot/modules/if_em.ko
...
7.6.2
...
```

So, the `if_em_load="YES"` is loading the *old* em driver found in /boot/kernel. I suppose this isn't surprising since `man kldload` says it looks there, but /boot/defaults/loader.conf contains `module_path="/boot/modules"`.

Manually loading v7.6.2 via `kldload /boot/modules/if_em.ko` gives this output:

```
em0: <Intel (R) PRO/1000 Network Connection 7.6.1-k> mem 0xdf300000-0xdf31ffff irq 16 at device 31.6 on pci0
em0: Using an MSI interrupt
em0: The EEPROM Checksum Is Not Valid
device_attach: em0 attach returned 5
em0: <Intel (R) PRO/1000 Network Connection 7.6.2> mem 0xdf300000-0xdf31ffff irq 16 at device 31.6 on pci0
em0: Using an MSI interrupt
em0: The EEPROM Checksum Is Not Valid
device_attach: em0 attach returned 5
```

So, still having the EEPROM Checksum issue, but another question is why does the `kldload` attempt to load v7.6.1 before v7.6.2, which is the file it is explicitly pointed to?

Finally, I decided to see what happens if I ignore the checksum check, which required patching `if_em.c` and `if_lem.c`, the two places the string "The EEPROM Checksum Is Not Valid" exist in the driver code.

Like so

```
--- if_em.c 2017-05-16 01:44:07.189792000 -0700
+++ if_em_patch.c   2017-05-16 01:44:28.885779000 -0700
@@ -730,10 +730,10 @@
        ** if it fails a second time its a real issue.
        */
        if (e1000_validate_nvm_checksum(hw) < 0) {
-           device_printf(dev,
+           /*device_printf(dev,
                "The EEPROM Checksum Is Not Valid\n");
            error = EIO;
-           goto err_late;
+           goto err_late;*/
        }
    }
```

and like so

```
--- if_lem.c    2017-05-16 01:39:27.605399000 -0700
+++ if_lem_patch.c  2017-05-16 01:44:47.661294000 -0700
@@ -641,10 +641,10 @@
        ** if it fails a second time its a real issue.
        */
        if (e1000_validate_nvm_checksum(&adapter->hw) < 0) {
-           device_printf(dev,
+           /*device_printf(dev,
                "The EEPROM Checksum Is Not Valid\n");
            error = EIO;
-           goto err_hw_init;
+           goto err_hw_init;*/
        }
    }
```

Now, a `make; make install; restart` still gives me v7.6.1 in dmesg.boot, but running `kldunload if_em; kldload /boot/modules/if_em.ko` gives output like:

```
em0: <Intel (R) PRO/1000 Network Connection 7.6.1-k> mem 0xdf300000-0xdf31ffff irq 16 at device 31.6 on pci0
em0: Using an MSI interrupt
em0: The EEPROM Checksum Is Not Valid
device_attach: em0 attach returned 5
em0: <Intel (R) PRO/1000 Network Connection 7.6.2> mem 0xdf300000-0xdf31ffff irq 16 at device 31.6 on pci0
em0: Using an MSI interrupt
em0: Ethernet address: xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx
```

It works! And I can get an IP via `dhclient em0` and `ping 8.8.8.8` goes fine.

So, here are my questions:

1. Why is my EEPROM checksum wrong? I haven't done anything that could mess with the firmware or whatever this is. What can I do that fixes this (that isn't prefaced with a disclaimer à la "this shouldn't work for integrated adapters," like all the answers I've found--e.g. [this one](https://thesorcerer.wordpress.com/2011/07/01/guide-intel-82573l-gigabit-ethernet-with-ubuntu-11-04-and-fix-pxe-e05/))?
2. Why is the kernel still loading v7.6.1 when I explicitly tell it to load v7.6.2 with `kldload /boot/modules/if_em.ko`?
3. Why is the kernel loading v7.6.1 at boot when `module_path="/boot/modules"` in /boot/defaults/loader.conf? What can I do to *only* load v7.6.2? Do I have to delete /boot/kernel/if_em.ko? That seems slightly wrong.

I understand that I get to enjoy the "fun" (and really, it is fun) of getting all my hardware and software to work correctly when I choose to run FreeBSD, but this seems like a little much.

EDIT: After updating to 11.0-RELEASE-p9 now that network connectivity existed, the same problems remain with no change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## em0: The EEPROM Checksum Is Not Valid

As you write the EEPROM checksum is related to the firmware. I believe that you have found the fix yourself. The disclaimers seems to date back from the old `ibautil` days. This one reports success with Supermicro boards with [builtin NICs](https://forum.pfsense.org/index.php?topic=51404.0) and someone with an [Intel D975XBX2](https://communities.intel.com/thread/15845).

I would download the [latest version](https://downloadcenter.intel.com/download/19186) and make sure that I was able to list my adapter. If so - I would not be so scared to try to reset the PXE configuration. But YMMV.

The suggested fix for wrong checksum is to reset the PXE default configuration using:

```
bootutil -nic=1 -defcfg
```

-- or --

```
bootutil -all -defcfg
```

The options can be found in [bootutil.txt](https://downloadmirror.intel.com/19186/eng/bootutil.txt)

## module_path

You should verify how `module_path` is actually set on your system. You can do this with `kenv`.

```
# kenv module_path
/boot/kernel;/boot/modules
```

You can also verify it using [kldconfig](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?kldconfig) which even hints the solution:

```
# kldconfig -r
/boot/kernel;/boot/modules
```

It is `module_path` which determines the order and where to look for `.ko` files. The default is set in [sys/boot/common/module.c](https://github.com/freebsd/freebsd/blob/master/sys/boot/common/module.c). This would have been easier to understand if `module_path` was removed from `/boot/defaults/loader.conf` or [conf/73535](https://bugs.freebsd.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=73535) was implemented. I have been confused by this as well.

You can change it using `kldconfig`.

As `/boot/kernel` is updated by the system and part of the FreeBSD base system it may be wise not to touch it. On the other hand changing the path order might give surprises as well. I have seen other people suggest making a softlink from `/boot/kernel`.

Comment: This worked, using `BOOTUTILW64E.EXE` from Windows on the same computer and the options you mentioned. I'm still a bit confused why `kldload /path/to/module.ko` still looks through `module_path` before going to the absolute path provided, but that can be a problem for another time. After reflashing the firmware, the v7.6.1-k driver works fine on boot.

Comment: Great!

    If you specify a valid absolute path and `module_path` is searched first - then I would consider it a bug. But if you get an error such as "module already loaded" then it makes more sense. The loading code is in [module.c](https://github.com/freebsd/freebsd/blob/master/sys/boot/common/module.c)